# How to use non-capturing groups in Regex to skip intermediate characters in a text

Tags: regex

I have this sample text below:

1000031231

I need to capture a group that will have the value: 131231 that is it should ignore the zeros between the first non-zero digit and the other non-zero digits afterwards.

Any idea how to make this work?

Tried:

([123456789]?(?:0*)[123456789]*)

But the captured group returns the entire original string that is 1000031231.

Expected:

131231

Comment: "I do not understand why what I tried does not work." - You are collecting _all_ results of  the group `([1-9]?(?:0*)[1-9]*)`. This first group will always also include the zeros of the embedded "non-capturing" `(?:0*)` group.

Comment: Could the string be `"1000031001"`? If so, do you want the resultant string to be `"1311"` or `"131001"`? If the former just remove the zeroes, which doesn't even require a regular expression.

Comment: In case the string is "100031001" I want the result to be "131001"

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Could the string be `"12000000"` or `"00000012"`? Incidentally, when responding to comments asking for clarification (like this one) it's best to edit your question rather than responding with a comment. Readers should not be expected to read all the comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

If it is known that--as in the example--all the zeros in the string are grouped together (contiguous with one another) one need only replace each zero with an empty string. I will assume that there may be more than one group of zeroes.

Here are a few ways to do that. None use a non-capture group, however.

---

You can attempt to match the regular expression

```
^([1-9]*)0*(.*)
```

If there is a match your desired string will be `$1+$2` (which may be written differently in different languages.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4pLB4M/1)

Hover the cursor over each part of the regular expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.

---

If the regex engine supports `\K` (which resets the starting point of the reported match to the current string position and discards any previously-consumed characters),  you may convert the characters matched by the following regular expression to an empty string.

```
^[1-9]*\K0*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AaVKfs/1)

Languages whose regex engine support `\K` include PHP, perl, Ruby, R (with `perl=TRUE`) and Python (with its PyPI module).

---

If you use a language that supports variable-length lookbehinds, such as C++ and Javascript, you could replace matches of the following regular expression with empty strings.

```
(?<=^[1-9]*)0*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LBTT3H/1)

Comment: Hi Cary. I need the result in one group and not in two groups as in your example. I do not understand why what I tried does not work. I am testing online at https://regex101.com/

Comment: Regex engines are incapable of simultaneously matching two substrings that are separated by one or more characters.

Comment: @EyalGonen If you are using .NET, you can [capture a group multiple times](https://regex101.com/r/zqDtPr/1), but that's about it. Concatenating non-contiguous series of characters is simply not possible.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, InSync and all others who replied. I realize that what I tried to do will not work per your great explanations above. I will try other suggested options.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of removing all zeros from the input string is by simply *removing* them:

```
/0+/g  // replace this match with ""
```

in JavaScript this can be done with `String.replace()`:

```js
const test=`10000312000031
1100003100023000100008
000031231
100000000`.split("\n");

test.forEach(t=>console.log(t.replace(/0+/g,"")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not skip characters in a consecutive match, so you can not get multiple separated group values in a single group match.

> it should ignore the zeros between the first non-zero digit and the
> other non-zero digits afterwards.

There is not language mentioned, but without global matching you could use a single capture group to keep the digit 1-9, then match 1 or more times a zero and assert a digit 1-9 to the right.

```
([1-9])0+(?=[1-9])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0vAw00/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "1000031231",
  "100031001",
  "001000031231",
  "0100031001",
  "012300031001"
];
const regex = /([1-9])0+(?=[1-9])/;
strings.forEach(s => {
  const result = s.replace(regex, "$1")
  console.log(`${s} --> ${result}`);
});
```

Or if you want to replace multiple instances, you can use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string, followed by optional zeroes which you would then also keep in group 1, and if you can not use lookarounds you can also capture the last digit 1-9 in group 2 and use both groups in the replacement:

```
^(0*[1-9]+)0+([1-9])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IsMwe4/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "1000031231",
  "100031001",
  "001000031231",
  "0100031001",
  "012300031001"
];
const regex = /^(0*[1-9]+)0+([1-9])/g;
strings.forEach(s => {
  const result = s.replace(regex, "$1$2")
  console.log(`${s} --> ${result}`);
});
```